# Bypassing Dual Stack Lite

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I am currently having problems connecting to a VPN I need to work with.
Troubles started when my ISP began switching to Dual Stack Lite, meaning that users get a native ipv6 and no public ipv4. (Traffic is routed through ipv6) 
However, it seems I need a Ipv4 to connect to that VPN.
Calling my ISP and asking them to give me a public v4 address was of no use since they apparently don't give them to users anymore.

I was thinking of renting a VPN that supports ipv6, gives me a static ipv4 address and tunnel through that, routing all ipv4 traffic to me so that I am reachable for my work VPN. (I guess that would be a 4in6/4over6 routing)
Unfortunatly, it seems there are hardly any ipv6 vpn prodiver, or only some which are very expensive and want me to pay on an annual base.

Another idea was to get some kind of mobile device but I am not sure whether that would work.

Does anyone have an idea how I can bypass that stupid Dual Stack Lite?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can use openVPN with Dual Stack Lite. PPTN just doesn't work